# How to remove python directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, installation, pip

I am trying to install pip, but it's being installed in a wrong file. I have just installed python 3.9 but pip has been installed in the 2.7 folder.

How do i change that?

I installed it by running

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

it returned

```
Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.2.3-py2.7.egg
```

Comment: If it was installed in the 2.7 library folder, presumably you used some Python 2.7 installation method to install it. You are not revealing how exactly you installed it, so we can't tell you how to undo that. My recommendation would be to just leave it there unless it is actively hampering your use of Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Run this one-

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

This will install pip for Python 3.9 and make that pip default.
After that verify with-

```
pip -V
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to easyinstall pip because [starting with Python 3.4, it is included by default with the Python binary installers](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#key-terms) so use it freely with `-m pip`

```
python3.9 -m pip install <package>
```

or in Debian-based distros:

```
pip3.9 install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SET command in Windows CMD to temporarily set the default python for the current session.

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.9
```